# Getting instance of global network namespace in linux kernel module

Tags: linux, namespaces, kernel-module

I am writing a Linux kernel module and want to get a `struct net*` pointer to the global network namespace on the device. I tried the code below in my module initialization function:

```
// test-module.c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <net/net_namespace.h>

int init_dev (void)
{
    struct net *net1;

    printk ("Init Module\n");

    net1 = get_net_ns_by_pid(1); // getting NS for PID 1 (init process)
    if(net1 != NULL){
        printk ("Init Module --- Got net ns pointer \n");
    }
    else {
        printk ("Init Module --- Blank net ns pointer \n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void cleanup (void)
{
    printk ("Cleaning Up the Module\n");
    return;
}

module_init (init_dev);
module_exit (cleanup);
```

Makefile:

```
obj-m += test-module.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I can compile the module but when I try to insert the module using `sudo insmod test-module.ko` I get the error in dmesg:

```
test-module: Unknown symbol get_net_ns_by_pid (err 0)
```

I want to ask if anyone knows how to get the `struct net*` pointer.

Comment: Function `get_net_ns_by_pid` is exported as GPL symbol. For use it, you need appropriate `MODULE_LICENSE` call.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Tsyvarev, I added the following line at the end of file and it worked fine:

```
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```